# Prestashop change all products currencies after main currency change

Tags: prestashop, currency, product

Is it possible to do all products currency change in mysql, not manually updating every product in admin panel?
Would love to know which table holds such info.
Thank you,

EDIT:I did found

```
ps_specific_prices, changing currency_id and multiplying prices.
```

Hoping for a miracle :)

EDIT2: 
It did not change. I'm still getting

```
$current_currency = $currency->iso_code; // <- LTL
$default_currency = Currency::getDefaultCurrency()->iso_code; // EUR
```

But I've changed to Eur in products table and in specific prices. What else?
 Backend shows good specific prices and normal price. Any ideas?

PS version 1.4.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All is done correctly, browser cache/cookies must be cleared. Thanks